# Running an titanium based ios app i got following error"Cannot read property 'devices' of undefined

Tags: ios, sdk, titanium, appcelerator

[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1

2017-11-21T06:35:06.273Z | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!

Cannot read property 'devices' of undefined

2017-11-21T06:35:06.274Z | ERROR  | Cannot read property 'devices' of undefined

2017-11-21T06:35:06.275Z | TRACE  | TypeError: Cannot read property 'devices' of undefined

```
at iOSBuilder.<anonymous> (/Users/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.4.0.GA/iphone/cli/commands/_build.js:298:12)

at /Users/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.4.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/index.js:115:12
```

I am not sure whats wrong.can anyone suggest me?

Answer (score 0):

I get rid of this error by downgrading the version of nodejs. You can try.